# MVC 5 with ASP.NET Identity - Get Claims when user logs in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, claims-based-identity

I am using OWIN 2.0, and after I log in a user, I want to retrieve an existing claim from the database but if I try to get the user's claims they are empty. If I put the same code in any of the subsequent controllers that gets called then the claims are there. It seems that the claims are not available until the next request after the initial login. Why is this?

```
var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var testClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims.Where(r => r.Type == "TestClaim").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly because you haven't passed the claims into the initial login (or have missed calling `CreateIdentityAsync`)?

With an out-of-the-box MVC5 application, I do this in the `SignInAsync` method:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    //Get the given name from somewhere
    var givenName = GetGivenName();

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, givenName));

    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

And this is called from the `Login` action.

Comment: You're right when I used the identity returned from CreateIdentityAsync() it works, thanks!!

Comment: What if I don't use the UserManager? and create the identity via new ClaimsIdentity(), why it still doesn't work?

Comment: @Christian I think you need to ask a new question, with the specific code that you are using.

Comment: My out of the box MVC5 application doesn't have a SignInAsync method. The `Login` action calls `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` but it is a built-in method, not in my source code. What class is yours in?

Comment: My out of the box MVC 5 application doesn't have a UserManager class, where is this?